# Reactjs Link does not work on IE11 but does on Edge and other browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, routes

I have the following code:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import DetailsOneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ListAlt';
import DetailsTwoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PlaylistAddCheck';

const OrderItemActions = ({ order, classes }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Tooltip title="Details 1 page">
                <IconButton aria-label="My details">
                    <Link to={`/orders/${order.orderReference}/details1`}>
                        <DetailsOneIcon />
                    </Link>
                </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Tooltip title="Details 2 page">
                <IconButton aria-label="My details 2">
                    <Link to={`/orders/${order.orderReference}/detail2`}>
                        <DetailsTwoIcon />
                    </Link>
                </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const getWarehouseOrder = warehouseOrder();

    return (state, { order }) => getWarehouseOrder(state, order.orderReference);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(OrderItemActions));
```

And I'm on these versions:

```
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
"react-redux": "^5.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
```

As the subject says, this does not work on IE11, it *does* work on Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

If I check network calls on the F12 console, I see no movement at all. So the underlying url call is not even attempted on IE11.

Usage of IE is dying out, but at this time I still have an official requirement to support IE and Edge. So I need to fix this.

> Any pointers?

**UPDATE**

It's the IconButton causing the situation, if I remove this:

```
<IconButton aria-label="My details">
```

Clicking the buttons works fine.

PS: This is a follow up to my previous question:

[What's the proper way to link to a route with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474881/whats-the-proper-way-to-link-to-a-route-with-parameters/54474927?noredirect=1#comment95758663_54474927)

Comment: Did you have your developer console open, before pressing the link? One quirk of IE is that it only logs when the developer tools are open

Comment: That is indeed a common pitfall, but I've had that happen enough to me :). I opened and did a reload/retry.

Comment: IE doesn't support template literals. Change `\`/orders/${order.orderReference}/details1\`` to `"/orders/" + order.orderReference + "/details1"`

Comment: @ChrisG: Thanks for the input but this does not seem to be the issue. See my update above. It works with the above change, so I'm inclined the already linked babel does it's job.

Comment: For testing purpose, Just try to make a sample with <IconButton aria-label="My details"> and try to run this code may help to narrow down the issue and it can give some idea about the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

React.js it's just modern javascript code and you can solve your problem if correct configure your babel
try change .babelrc for ie 11

```
{
  "presets" : [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 11"]
      }
    }],
    "react",
  ]
}
```

Comment: I did not yet have a `.babelrc` file, I do have a dependency link to `"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"` in `package.json` though. Should I just add the file, or does it need to be linked?

Comment: i recommend add this file